# moving plot dynamic by grouping

Tags: plot, highcharts

I try to do a highchairs code to make a Moving line with reality time ( manual action)

the first point it the same that standard line and can't be Moving

the other point can be Moving right or left

when I move the second point, it ok the other point move too

but when I move the 3 points (or more ) the 2nd point move too and it's not ok, I need the behind point not move

I try to do with groupid solution…
I select x point, the point x+1,x+2,x+3 move too but the point x-1, x-2 don't group with ( so don't move)

how can I group and ungrouped when I move point?

how can I do to limit min selected point to not move left behind x-1 point?

thank for your help

i do this code : [jsfiddle.net/arawn45/60bdzu4o/14/](http://jsfiddle.net/arawn45/60bdzu4o/14/)

a piece of code :

```
 groupId: 'Group A',
```

Comment: sorry for my bad English, thank to help me

Answer (score 0):

i find a solution to limite move point Under data

```
                if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y', new Date(this.x)) ==
                (Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y',  Date.UTC(1970, 10, 9)))) {
                    setDragStatus('erreur condition 1 '+Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y', new Date(this.x))+' ');
                    return false;
                }
```

i dont know how to do that

if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y', new Date(this.x)) <
                    (date point-1 )

…
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In `mouseOver` event function you can reduce the number of dragged points by changing `groupId` property for points with lower x value:

```
series: [{
    point: {
        events: {
            mouseOver: function() {
                var points = this.series.points;

                points.forEach(function(point, i) {
                    if (i && point.x < this.x) {
                        point.update({
                            groupId: false
                        }, false);
                    }
                }, this);
            },

            mouseOut: function() {
                var points = this.series.points;

                points.forEach(function(point, i) {
                    if (i) {
                        point.update({
                            groupId: 'Group A'
                        }, false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },
    ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/apqbd3ft/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.point.events.mouseOver

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.point.events.mouseOut

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Answer (score 0):

thanks very much
it look like what i want to do

juste add  a limite when i move point to left, before this point.date than point-1.date.

thanks